# Can't Install Correct Kernel Headers

Tags: centos

I'm trying to setup R1Soft backups and I run into the error

> Could not find a suitable hcpdriver module for your system; Please run "r1soft-setup --get-module " on your Agent to install one.

So to resolve I've run the `r1soft-setup --get-module` command which tells me

> Please install the kernel headers for your operating system.

To do this I run 
`yum install kernel-devel`

Which tells me

> Package kernel-devel-2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
>   Nothing to do

I check my kernal version using `uname -r` and I see my kernal version is actually`2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64`

I then try install the headers for this kernel by running
`yum install kernel-devel-$(uname -r)`
and 
`yum install kernel-devel-$(uname -r) --disableexcludes=all`

Each time I get back the message

> No package kernel-devel-2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64 available.
>   Error: Nothing to do

Now I'm at a bit of a loss as to what to do. It would appear that I'm running a different kernel than yum thinks I'm on, but also that the headers for the kernel I want just aren't available (according to yum)

Anyone know how I can get the correct headers so I can setup the hcpdriver module? I'm running CENTOS 6.8 on a virtual server from a hosting company

Answer (score 1):

Kernel 2.6.32-431 is an old one and isn't in repositories already. So no related packages are there too. You should update your kernel (the latest one is 2.6.32-642.11.1, the same as you -devel package) and boot into it.

Anyway headers are within `kernel-headers` package.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to manually install the correct devel package from pbone.net by using the command below

```
rpm -ivh --force ftp://mirror.switch.ch/pool/4/mirror/scientificlinux/6.5/x86_64/updates/security/kernel-devel-2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64.rpm
```